# Disable JSHint warning for function: variable is defined but never used

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have the following js code:

```
      allRejectedByPatient = survey.resultSent.every(function(element, _index, _array) {
        return (element.patientConfirmed === false);
      });
```

This code returns following errors when I run eslint:

```
W: '_index' is defined but never used.
W: '_array' is defined but never used.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Don't define them ? `function(element) {`

Comment: Please refer https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars

Comment: @Rajesh It's about JSHint, not ESLint.

Comment: @hsz please check the tag. It says `eslint`. Hence I shared a reference doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the variables that you are defining(_index, _array are not being used anywhere in the code). So change it to this instead:

```
allRejectedByPatient = survey.resultSent.every(function(element) {
        return (element.patientConfirmed === false);
      });
```